# MYSQL IN alternative

Tags: mysql

I am coding a social networking type website, users have friends and I am trying to create a news feed with actions that their friends have done

I have three tables

Users

```
id     |    username
---------------------
1      |    john
2      |    nicole
3      |    bob
```

Friends

```
id     |    uid    |    who
----------------------------
1      |     1     |     2
2      |     2     |     1
3      |     2     |     3
4      |     3     |     2
5      |     3     |     1
6      |     1     |     3
```

Actions

```
id    |    owner    |  to_id  |    message 
-------------------------------------------
1     |     3       |    2    |     'hello'
2     |     3       |    1    |     'yoooo'
```

Since 'john' is friends with 'bob, 'john' should be able to see 'bob' action to 'nicole'

EDIT:: I also want to get the actions from the other direction, if 'nicole' sends an action to 'bob'

My current solution is:

have a string that contains all the friends of a user: $friends = '1,2,3,4....etc'

query:

```
SELECT 
   `Actions`.*
FROM 
   `Actions` 
WHERE 
   (`Actions`.`to_id` IN (${friends}) OR  `Actions`.`from_id` IN (${friends})) 
   AND
   ( `Actions`.`to_id` != (${logged_id} AND `Actions`.`from_id` != (${logged_id})
ORDER BY
    `Actions`.`time` ASC
LIMIT 
    15
```

The above query works, but my problem is when users start have hundreds of friends this query will be  horrendously slow, what can I do as an alternative to prevent this?

Comment: Does the id column in the friends table serve any purpose?

Comment: it servers no purpose, would you recommend to remove it?

Comment: your other alternative is that; join the tables and make the query, but if i am not wrong the `IN`  stament is faster than joining the tables

Comment: i suggest you to use nosql databases such as mongo instead of reletional database model if your project is not finished yet

Answer (score 1):

If you want to try a different and better solution, please try using any popular graph database. It is well suited for your current requirement.

Answer (score 1):

What about using a JOIN to achieve this?

```
SELECT actions.* 
FROM actions a 
JOIN friends f ON f.who = a.owner 
WHERE f.uid = (current user's ID)
LIMIT 15
```

(Returns 15 actions owned by friends of the current user.)